# How to delete a @ManyToOne @NotNull reference?

Tags: validation, jpa, many-to-one

Assume I have an `Entity0`

```
@Entity
public class Entity0 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Entity1 entity1;

    public Entity0() {
    }

    public Entity0(Long id,
            Entity1 entity1) {
        this.id = id;
        this.entity1 = entity1;
    }

    [getter and setter for id and entity1]
}
```

which references `Entity1`

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    private String property0;

    public Entity1() {
    }

    public Entity1(Long id,
            String property0) {
        this.id = id;
        this.property0 = property0;
    }

    [getter and setter for id and property0]
}
```

The `@NotNull` annotation is useful to assert that `Entity0.entity1` is set during `persist` and `merge`. However, it disallows to delete the reference to `Entity1` (set it to `null` and merge the instance into the persistence context) which is necessary to delete instance of `Entity1` which are referenced. I'm wondering whether there's any way to have a `@ManyToOne @NotNull` property in an entity at all. The following illustrates the problems which arise from the different approaches I took to make it possible to delete `Entity1` instances from persistence:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("de.richtercloud_jpa-not-nulll-many-to-one-removal_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1(2l, "abc");
Entity0 entity0 = new Entity0(1l, entity1);
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(entity1);
entityManager.persist(entity0);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entity1 = entityManager.merge(entity1);
entity0 = entityManager.merge(entity0);

//1: fails due to `ERROR 23503: DELETE on table 'ENTITY1' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK5CQRG47R3H3KQG834IH36DUB' for key (2).  The statement has been rolled back.`
//entityManager.remove(entity1);
//entityManager.flush();
//entityManager.merge(entity0);
//entityManager.flush();

//2:
entity0.setEntity1(null);
entityManager.remove(entity1);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.merge(entity0);
entityManager.flush();

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
```

The code contains so many `flush`s because I'm reproducing this for a JTA-environment where a flush can occur between the parts of a transaction.

I'm aware that I can drop the `@NotNull` annotation to work around the problem. My question is whether there's any solution to have both annotations and be able to delete. In case that's no possible, is it more common to set the reference temporarily to a bogus `Entity1` instance or to give up on `@NotNull`?

Cascading might be a valid way, if not *the* way, however I've given up on it because I found it to be hiding issues and behaving in an unwanted fashion - not that it's not possible to master, it's just easier to handle for me personally.

Comment: You have NotNull, so the property may not be null. So settting it to null doesn't make much sense. If you want it to not reference entity1 anymore, you need to make it reference another Entity1 instance: `entity0.setEntity1(anotherEntity1); entityManager.remove(entity0);`

Comment: Is cascading a valid way for you? If entity1 is deleted then entity0 should be deleted as well because it relies on entity1. Otherwise you have to change the reference of entity0 to another entity1. You can not set it to null

Comment: @PatrickLauhof Thanks for you input. I added a note to the question. It's probably the best approach, although I always feel bad - more precisely not in control - if I use any form of JPA cascading. Is there any way to cascade a single deletion in a provider-portable way?

Answer (score 0):

If cascading is a way you could add the following to your entity1

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) 
private List<Entity0> entity0s;
```

This way the referenced entity0s will be deleted when entity1 is deleted.
Cascading can be dangerous and you should always think twice about it whether it is a good idea to always delete the referenced entities. Sometimes it is better to delete the references first and then remove the "parent" entity.

Comment: It's not a bi-directional relationship, only the entity relationships shown in the question.

Comment: That is the way cascading works. If you dont want to use it that way you have to delete the entities manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see what the problem is, why do you think you have to set `@NotNull` on a `@ManyToOne` foreign key declaration? `@NotNull` is not a JPA annotation. If you want to make the database column set to not null you should use:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id", nullable=false)
private Entity1 entity1;
```

So if you want to have `nullable=false` and delete them both then delete the child first then the parent.

```
tx.begin();
entity1 = em.find(Entity1.class, 1L);
entity0 = em.find(Entity0.class, 2L);
em.remove(entity0);
em.remove(entity1);
tx.commit();
```

Comment: I _want_ the `@NotNull` annotation so that I have a consistent scheme of validation and exceptions which I can catch to provide user feedback.

Comment: I can't imagine how the user is creating relationships from a form. If they didn't fill out enough information for Entity1 to exist then you have bigger issues. Remember, write code like someone else has to work on it. Throwing random nonsense like this into your code is *not* doing yourself or anyone else any favors.